# Pictures are cut on my Tumblr blog

Tags: tumblr

On my Tumblr blog I don't understand why images in Photoset are cut, so we can't see all their height.

For example, one picture is 700px width by 394px height, but what we see is 700px width by 383px height, so 11px are missing !

Here is the page:
http://www.scarabeearchitecture.fr/

Here is the CSS for photos and photoset:

```
.posts {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 1024px;
     margin: 0 auto 48px;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
     padding: 0px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -o-border-radius: 3px;
     -ms-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
 }

 .posts_inner {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 700px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding-bottom: 26px;
     word-break: break-word;
 }

 .chat .posts_inner,
 .link .posts_inner {
     width: 87%;
     max-width: 700px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

 .audio_inner {
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 .photo .posts_inner,
 .video .posts_inner,
 .audio .posts_inner,
 .quote .posts_inner,
 .link .posts_inner {
     width: 100%!important;
     max-width: 1024px!important;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

 .photo .posts_inner .date,
 .video .posts_inner .date,
 .audio .posts_inner .date,
 .quote .posts_inner .date,
 .link .posts_inner .date,
 ul.tags {
     width: 100%!important;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

 #permalinkpage .posts_inner p {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

 .photoset-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .video-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .audio-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .quote-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .link-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .video-container {
     margin-top: 34px;
 }

 .quote_outer {
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-shadow: none;
     font-style: italic;
 }

 .chat_outer {
     margin-top: 16px;
 }

 .link_outer {
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: none;
 }

 .link_outer h2 {
     padding-bottom: 0!important;
     border-bottom: none!important;
 }

 .link_outer h2 a {
     font-size: 24px!important;
     font-weight: normal!important;
     color: #f2f2f2!important;
 }

 .link_outer a {
     color: #999999!important;
     font-size: 14px!important;
 }

 .link {
     padding-top: 22px;
 }

 .photoset-grid-lightbox_outer {
     padding: 0px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
 }

 .video-grid-lightbox_outer {
     padding: 3px 38px 38px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
 }

 .audio-grid-lightbox_outer,
 .quote-grid-lightbox_outer {
     padding: 38px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
 }

 .link-grid-lightbox_outer {
     padding: 44px 38px 58px 38px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), #333333 url(http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/tT8myt4ib/bg_noise.png) center;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
 }

 .photoset-grid-lightbox,
 .photopost,
 .video-container {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 50;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px gray;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px gray;
     -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px gray;
     -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px gray;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 20px gray;
     background: #000000;
 }

 .photoset-grid-lightbox:before,
 .photopost:before,
 .video-container:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 1px;
     z-index: 100;
     border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

 .photoset-grid-lightbox:after,
 .photopost:after,
 .video-container:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 100;
     border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

 .posts h2,
 #permalinkpage h2 {
     font-size: 28px;
     padding-bottom: 18px;
     border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
 }

 .posts h2 a {
   color: #333333;
   font-size: 28px;
 }

 .sp_show {
     display: none;
 }

 .posts p,
 #permalinkpage p {
     margin: 30px 0 30px;
     font-size: 14px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width : 768px){
     .posts {
         padding: 24px 0 0;
     }

     .posts_inner {
         width: 87%;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
     }

     .photo .posts_inner,
     .video .posts_inner {
         width: 95%;
     }

     .photoset-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .video-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .audio-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .quote-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .link-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .video-container {
         margin-top: 24px;
     }

     .video-grid-lightbox_outer {
         padding: 13px 38px 38px;
     }

     .photo .posts_inner .date,
     .video .posts_inner .date {
         width: 92%;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
     }

     .posts p,
     #permalinkpage p { 
         font-size: 1.6rem;
     }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width : 480px){
     .photoset-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .audio-grid-lightbox_outer,
     .video-grid-lightbox_outer {
         padding: 0;
         -webkit-box-shadow: none;
         -moz-box-shadow: none;
         -o-box-shadow: none;
         -ms-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
         background: none;
     }

     .photoset-grid-lightbox,
     .photopost,
     .video-container {
         -webkit-box-shadow: none;
         -moz-box-shadow: none;
         -o-box-shadow: none;
         -ms-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
     }

     .audio-grid-lightbox_outer {
         width: 87%;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
     }

     .pc_show {
         display: none;
     }

     .sp_show {
         display: inline;
     }

     .spotify_audio_player {
         max-width: 100%!important;
         height: 80px!important;
     }
 }

 .posts div.date a,
 .posts div.date,
 #permalinkpage div.date a,
 #permalinkpage div.date {
   color: #999999;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }

 .posts div.date a:hover {
   color: #006bd5;
 }

 .posts p.date {
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   text-align: right;
   color: #999999;
   font-size: 12px;
 }

 .posts p.date a {
   color: #999999;
 }

 .caption {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 35px auto 0;
 }

 .posts .link {
   font-size: 12px;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You're document is invalid. You have a doctype, followed by a misplaced script, followed by another doctype. Clean that mess up first.

Comment: Ok thank you, I placed better the script,
can you tell me more about doctype ?
we can add css information on html document no ?
which doctype should i use ?
thanks